# 'Removed Records: Hyperlinks...' when opening spreadsheet

Tags: export-to-excel, xlsxwriter

I am generating a spreadsheet based on ServiceNow data using xlsxwriter in Python.  When opening the spreadsheet, I am asked if I want Excel to attempt to repair the file.  When I say yes, I get this:

```
Removed Records: Hyperlinks from /xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml part
```

I renamed the xlsx file to .zip and extracted its contents as recommended in some documentation, but I honestly have no idea what I'm looking at.  A complicating factor is that the sheet1.xml file is quite large, about 80MB.  How do I figure out the cause of this?

A few more bits of information:

- By limiting the input rows, I can remove the message.  I suspect that I'm exceeding the number of hyperlinks allowed, but I'm not sure.
- As far as I know, there are no hyperlinks, or at least nothing I wanted to make clickable in the output data.  I would be happy if there were a way to tell xlsxwriter "nothing is a hyperlink... if you think it is, just call it text and move on".

I'm open to different approaches to this... It's a bit sticky to work on.  Thank you.

Comment: I am the author of XlsxWriter and I'd be interested in seeing the file that is causing this issue if you could raise a github issue or if the data is sensitive contact me at the email address in the [docs](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/author.html). In the meantime you can avoid creating unintentional hyperlinks by using the `strings_to_urls` [Constructor](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/workbook.html) parameter: `workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(filename, {'strings_to_urls': False})`.

Comment: Thank you, both for the reply and for writing a great tool.  I applied the parameter you suggested and no longer have the problem.  Again, thank you.  I'm not able to share the file without approval, as this is company data, but I will check into it.  Again, thank you.